# No standard / documentation on how to create component for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I have searched on Google and nothing comes up ?

So where can I find article on this ?

Something equivalent to this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973807.aspx
but for iOS

Comment: What kind of component do you mean?

Comment: It depends what type of component do you want to create. For example if you want to create a specific button you need to subclass UIButton class and add specific behaviours. Try to explain what is your intent.

Comment: Creating a complex component is not just about subclassing an existing component: what if I want to create an interactive gauge for example ?

Comment: Have you read any of Apple's documentation? For example, the View Programming Guide has an entire section on [Defining a Custom View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23) . Also the [iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) provide some good documentation on how controls should act on the platform.

Comment: OK for customview. And how does I add it to the standard components toolbar in the IDE ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set of classes and an assocated xib file that you can use in your project. There are many examples of this, such an [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) on GitHub.

If you are asking about creating such a control that you can add to Xcode, so that you can add it to your projects and configure it from Xcode - you can't. The latest major version of Xcode (Xcode 4) removed support for Interface Builder plugins.

Comment: The latest major version of Xcode (Xcode 4) removed support for Interface Builder plugins. ? Isn't this a regression ?

Comment: No. If they remove support for it that's a design decision and not a regression. Xcode 4 has a lot of changes from Xcode 3. They might put it back in, they might not. But if, right now, you want to create a component that you can add to Interface builder, drop onto your views and configure from within IB - you can't.

Comment: It's a decision to make a feature regression ;)